# Android keyboard slides down leaving white space behind screen

Tags: android

When I am using the fragment keyboard slides down leaving the white space behind screen, here is the screen shot!

When I use without list view nothing come but when I use list view that white screen is appearing

[image]

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/list_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/abs__search_src_text"
                        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                        android:layout_height="36.0dip"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textNoSuggestions"
                        android:minWidth="160.0dip"
                        android:paddingLeft="8.0dip"
                        android:paddingRight="8.0dip"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" >

                        <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>
```

Comment: post the xml and code ...

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin after using the fragment it leaves the white space for a while even after disabling keyboard

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin here is my class file code for edittextchatMessageEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  
   public void onClick(View v) {
    
    emoticonsCover.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
    smileyclick = false;
    plus_click = false;
    plus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    close.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    linearLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    linearLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (servermessage) {
     relativeLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } 
    else 
    {
     relativeLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
   }
  });

Comment: in the androidmanifest file u have to set the activity property as  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"

Comment: like this 
 <activity
            android:name="BaseActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" >
        </activity>

Comment: in this u have set the android:windowSoftInputMode and android:configChanges like the above

Comment: @Nithinlal still its not working ever after add this

Comment: @Nithinlalsorry still not working even after add all those things.. can u pls give the reason